# SAS Code for regular expression

Tags: regex, sas

I have an address string thats space delimited, I'm trying to replace the second argument with the third. The code I posted below doesn't work. Please help me correct it.

```
data sasuser.word_exchange;
set sasuser.testnew3;
retain re1 re2 ;
if _N_ = 1 then do;
re1 = prxparse('s/DR/DRIVE/');
re2= prxparse('s/AVE/AVENUE/');
end;
call prxchange( re1,-1, strip(CITYSTATE));
call prxchange( re2,-1, strip(CITYSTATE));
RUN;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use STRIP in that context.  Here's an example using /io (i=case insensitive, o=compile once, so no need for the if *n*=1 block).  'i' may be undesirable depending on your data.

```
data have;
input @1 CITYSTATE $200.;
infile datalines truncover;
datalines;
2001 Bellini Ave Michigan City IN 58431
123 Anywhere Dr Boston MA 00123
456 Nowhere Lane New York City NY 10035
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have;
re1 = prxparse('s/DR/DRIVE/io');
re2= prxparse('s/AVE/AVENUE/io');
call prxchange( re1,-1, CITYSTATE);
call prxchange( re2,-1, CITYSTATE);
put CITYSTATE=;
RUN;
```

Comment: I'd also note that this is probably a very bad idea as conceived here.  This will change all "DR" to "DRIVE" even if it's part of, say, "Driscoll CT" -> "DRIVEiscoll, CT".  You need to include boundary checks if you want to verify that you are changing a " DR " or similar.